# Single word Adjective or noun for a person who always toes the line (to irritating level)

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word Adjective or noun for a person who always toe the line (to irritating level).

There is a hindi equivalent for it "Laqeer ka fakir" which is "marking line's beggar". The meaning is one who begs to follow the marking line which is equivalent to "toe the line".

Comment: You mean _servile_ ?

Comment: The expression "blind obedience" is quite commonly used. Also [obedience to authority](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-lawsocsci-110316-113710?journalCode=lawsocsci)

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to find a condensation of meaning to one word. Three possibilities are:

*Running-dog* = one who blindly follows someone else's orders

*Lackey* = a servile follower

*Flunkey* = a person who does unimportant work or who has few or no important responsibilities and shows too much respect toward his or her employer:

All from Merriam Webster dictionary. The choice will depend on context.

If the person is merely compliant to rules rather than to a person, they might also be described as a *rule-follower*.